# Trying to do a LEFT JOIN with two select queries on mysqli

Tags: mysql

Both queries work separately, but I need them in a single table.
Im trying to save all posts by the users followers + their own posts in a single table

table following(ID, User, FollowingUser) -> saves which user follows another user

Query 1- Selects all of the posts from the current user's followers

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostID, posts.UserID, FollowingUser, Name, Date, Post 
FROM following, users, posts 
WHERE (User=1 AND users.UserID=FollowingUser AND posts.UserID=FollowingUser)
```

Query 2- Selects all of posts made by the current user

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostID, posts.UserID, null, Name, Date, PostID
FROM users, posts
WHERE UserID=1
```

Comment: Look into UNION

Comment: If anyone's wondering, the result table is supposed to hold a post feed for the user, orderded by Date DESC

Comment: Implicit, "comma", join notation is generally out of favor, and has been for the better part of a decade or two; if you're talking about left joins, you really should convert to modern explicit join notation as the different notations generally do not play well together. ...but as Jordan S said, UNION is more likely what you need anyway. _Also, that second query doesn't get all the posts by user 1, it combines ALL posts with user 1's info._

Comment: @Uueerdo Can you support your statement, please?

Comment: @Jordan S, yes thanks union is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @Uueerdo and thank you correcting that second query mistake for me :)

Comment: @Dharman I'll happily endorse Uueerdo's remarks. Further, the manual is quite authoritative on the matter.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't use the comma notation myself, for the sole reason of clarity. But I have never seen in the docs that the comma notation is discouraged. If Uueerdo is giving such statement I expect some supporting links to docs or other SO questions.

Comment: [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018825/1839439)